# I'm trying to append 25 files row-wise containing the same column header into a single dataframe in R

Tags: r

I've mentioned the directory location and trying to iterate over the files, but the following doesn't seem to work.

file_list <- list.files()
    file_list

```
for (file in file_list){

  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }

}
```

I'm using this code, however it's giving an odd output, with several warnings:

> Warning messages:
>      1: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
>   2: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'File_0.XLSX'
>   3: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
>   4: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'File_0.XLSX'
>   5: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'File_1.XLSX'
>   6: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'File_10.XLSX'
>   7: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'File_11.XLSX'
>   8: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'File_12.XLSX'
>   9: In read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'File_13.XLSX'

What do these warnings mean? Where am I going wrong. I don't want to write RBIND for all these.

Comment: read.table is for text files. Yours appear to be xlsx files

Comment: suggest you to install the `xlsx` package to read the files. refer [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html). Also, your R needs to be on the same architecture as your Java, for the package to work (read and write). Or, you could use my udf for it - `install_github('samkart/readwrite/readwrite')`. Documentation included.

Comment: I'm getting "File cannot be opened error", how to resolve it?